# Modal Show Command Not Working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

My Code:

```
$("#ContentAire").append('<div id="'+ ID +'" class="modal fade" .......');
$("#"+ ID + "").modal("show");`
```

I want to show modal but it's not working.
what i tried didn't work please help.

ERR:

```
APIManager.js:50 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at InitReportModal (APIManager.js:50:25)
    at Object.success (APIManager.js:30:39)
    at c (Jquery.js:2:28447)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (Jquery.js:2:29192)
    at l (Jquery.js:2:80176)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (Jquery.js:2:82630)
```

Comment: Are you importing the dependency for `.modal`?